# Bind click and live click

Tags: jquery

Why this code works [(see code at jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzezc/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = '<div><a href="javascript:">click me</a></div>';
    var $div = $(html);
    $div.find('a').bind('click', function() { //attention on bind
        alert('Hi');
    });
    $('#test').append($div);
});
```

but the same code with `.bind('click'` replaced with `.live('click'` is not working? Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you replace the $(document).ready with .live('click') ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) says:

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send
>   to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called
>   directly after a selector.

So if you change `$div.find('a').bind('click'` to `$('#test a').live('click'` it would work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use delegate instead like this:

```
var $div = $('<div><a href="javascript:">click me</a></div>');
$div.delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    alert('Hi');
});
$('#test').append($div);
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzezc/11/)

Comment: I like it, but you make the same mistake as OP's: you use `$div` as if it was global, but nothing shows it is.

Comment: Not sure that it made much difference? But I've changed it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not replace $(document).ready with .live('click') by nest it. The cause of your problem may be that the document is not fully loaded yet, so the binding is not working.

So try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('mybutton').live('click', function(){ ... });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .bind() on a specific html element (here : $div > a) but the .live() function is different : it applies to elements of the same kind (like $("div > a")).

So you can change `$div.find('a').bind('click',` in `$('div > a').live('click',`

Answer (score 0):

Great article on [differences between jQuery .bind() vs .live() vs .delegate() vs .on() :  http://www.elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/